# Looking for clarification of getopts specifications for ksh

Tags: ksh, getopts

Years ago, I found [this reference](https://docstore.mik.ua/orelly/unix3/korn/appb_11.htm) to some details behind advanced use of getopts in KornShell scripts.  This is an excellent reference as far as it goes, but looking at some other code from other sources, it is clear that this is not the definitive standard for getopts within KornShell.  And, since it's simply an example, much is left to the imagination regarding what can be done here.

Digging deeper, I recently found [this Oracle reference](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E88353_01/html/E37839/getopts-1.html) that does provide more detail, which I appreciate.

But I have found inclarities in the descriptions.

For example, 'An option argument specification consists of the option argument name as field 1.'  Exactly what is an argument name, and how is it used?  Another example, same paragraph, is mention of a "type name," but again, I do not find any clarity in what a type name is, and how it is used.  Only its title.

Also, where 'An argument specification' is mentioned, there is scant detail about the formatting and use of "option argument values," only stating 'A list of valid option argument values can be specified by enclosing them inside a {...} following the option argument specification. Each of the permitted values can be specified with a [...] containing the value followed by a description.'  Here, the mention of brackets and braces is confusing at best, and ambiguous at worst.

I'm not here to put down this excellent documentation - and not interested in doing so. These are great helps to handling probably the bulk of what people want to do with getopts. What I am looking for, is a clear explanation of - especially - these argument specifications and how the list of options can be specified.  I've tried a few options like:

```
USAGE+="[b:is-batch]:[IS_BATCH_ARG:ignorecase:=NO{[YES][NO][Y][N]}]"
```

The result of the above is this:

```
OPTIONS
    -b, --is-batch=IS_BATCH_ARG The default value is NO{}
```

Also, clarity around the other things I mentioned (type name, and an option argument name) would be very helpful for me.

I'm trying to put together a fairly complex script that has a lot of parameters (some yes/no - which might benefit from 'list of values'), and this looks like the ideal tool to complete what's needed - I especially like the automatic --man option!  But various combinations of things aren't quite achieving my expectation after reading those pages.

Is there someone reading this who can help me understand how these finer details of the getopts function would be properly implemented, so that I may exploit it to its potential?

Thanks.

Comment: What ksh version are you using?

Comment: @glennjackman > ksh --version  result is "version sh (AT&T Research) 2020.0.0"  This is on Ubuntu 20.04.3

Comment: The Oracle documentation looks pretty comprehensive, if a little confusing. `ksh88` V `ksh` is almost certainly `ksh88` is older than `ksh` which is referred to in Korn's book as `ksh93`. Assuming that when you execute `echo ${.sh.version}` it outputs something about  `ksh93` you should focus on the explanations for `ksh`. (not `ksh88`).  

Ksh is still being developed and if you search for `getopts` in https://github.com/ksh93/ksh/blob/dev/docs/ksh/faq.html you'll find some hints. I don't have time to dig thru the `git` to see where the `--man` or `man` pages are. Good luck.

Comment: You may find that the only way you can  understand the descriptions is to do small experiments. Your sample above is relatively complex. Getting one feature to work at a time, and "glue" them together after you understand how the small pieces are supposed to work together (It seems like you may be doing that). Just all IMHO. Good luck.

Comment: `option argument specification`, `option argument name`, `argument specification'` and the other terms you are puzzling over (rightly (-;! ) .. I think are defined in the `ksh93` man page near the top. Unfortunately, these are not tutorial documents, the are the basic definitions and you'll have to explore what some of those definitions mean. Again, Good luck.

Comment: Thanks @shellter.  Trial and error may get me the output results I want (eventually, but not necessarily reliably).  Trial and error will not provide insight into how, for example, argument name is used... nor the complete list of values for argument types, et cetera.  I did have a look at that github link you provided.  There are two references to getopts there, each is only a mention of the name.  A shame, this seems to have been lost somewhere along the line (which further implies nobody is maintaining it).  I do appreciate your attention.